# OOM killer killing Java in Dataflow worker

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a fairly simple streaming Dataflow pipeline reading from pubsub and writing to BigQuery using BATCH_LOADS (with streaming engine enabled).  We do have one version of this pipeline working, but it seems very fragile, and simple additions to the code seem to tip it over and the worker process starts to eat up memory.

- Sometimes the Java heap fills up, gets java.lang.OutOfMemoryError, dumps the heap, and jhat shows the heap is full of Windmill.Message objects.
- More often, the machine gets really slow (kernel starts swapping), then the kernel OOM killer kills Java.

Today I have further evidence that might help debug this issue: a live worker (compute.googleapis.com/resource_id: "1183238143363133621") that started swapping but managed to come out of that state without crashing.  The worker logs show that the Java heap is using 1GB (total memory), but when I ssh into the worker, "top" shows the Java process is using 3.2GB.

What could be causing Java to use so much memory outside of its heap?

I am using Beam 2.15 PubsubIO, and a clone of Beam's BigQueryIO with some modifications.  I have tried increasing to a larger machine size, but it only delays the failure.  It still eventually fills up its memory when the pubsub subscription has a lot of backlog.

**EDIT:**

Some more details: The memory issues seem to happen earlier in the pipeline than BigQueryIO.  There are two steps between PubsubIO.Read and BigQueryIO.Write: Parse and Enhance.  Enhance uses a side input, so I suspect fusion is not being applied to merge those two steps.  Triggers are very slow to fire (why?), so Enhance is slow to start due to the side input's Combine.Globally being delayed by about 3 mintues, and even after it is ready, WriteGroupedRecords is sometimes called 10 minutes after I know the data was ready.  When it is called, it is often with way more than 3 minutes-worth of data.  Often, especially when the pipeline is just starting, the Parse step will pull close to 1000000 records from pubsub. Once Enhance starts working, it will quickly process the 1000000 rows and turn them into TableRows.  Then it pulls more and more data from pubsub, continuing for 10 minutes without WriteGroupedRecords being called.  It seems like the runner is favoring the earlier pipeline steps (maybe because of the sheer number of elements in the backlog) instead of firing window triggers that activate the later steps (and side inputs) as soon as possible.

Comment: What are you setting for the triggering frequency and what are you setting for the number of file shards? Also, what are your modifications to BigQueryIO? (Note that BigQuery BATCH_LOADS uses GroupByKey to buffer data and writes all the records within X time to Y keys so you need to ensure that the amount of data you process within X time divided by Y files fits within a single machines memory.) It would also be useful if you could tell us where the Windmill.Message objects were allocated.

Comment: @LukaszCwik, first I'll answer your questions. Trigger freq=3 minutes; shards=1. I'm trying to summarize the data being loaded, making BigQueryIO.Write kind of a sink+CombineFn hybrid. So input into BigQueryIO.Write is a TableRow+CombineInput, output from BigQueryIO is a CombineResult (one for each load job).  I have also experimented with changing Window(triggered on 500000 or 3 minutes)+WriteGroupedRecords to a Window(triggered every 3 minutes)+CombineFn that writes grouped records as needed.  I have the hprof file saved, but it'll take me a while to extract info about Windmill.Messages.

Comment: What concerns me more than the Windmill.Messages is how much non-Java-heap memory is being used by the Java process.  Even with the Java heap less than 50% allocated (maxMemory > totalMemory*2), the worker machine slows to a crawl due to paging (SSHD takes 10 minutes to respond making it difficult to connect to the worker, and fluentd stops sending logs to stackdriver in a timely manner).  Eventually either the kernel OOM killer kills Java, or the instance group manager detects lack of responsiveness and respawns a new worker.  But this takes a while (sometimes an hour or two).

Comment: I edited the question with more details. Basically, as I see it, the RAM requirements are unbounded due to the lack of backpressure from later steps and due to non-determinism of triggers.

Comment: I tihink I would advise you to file a support ticket to understand why these things are causing trouble : /

Comment: Is there any update on this? We are facing very similar problem